# When does a question stop to be specific for Drupal?

Tags: support, questions

When does a question stop to be Drupal specific?

A question that is about [an error reported by Firebug](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3143/syntax-error-doctype-html-line-1-in-firebug) about the document type is a Drupal specific question, or is it a general question?

What is the criteria that allow to decide which questions are not Drupal specific?
I think that the fact the error appeared when using Drupal doesn't automatically make it a Drupal problem. There should be more restrictive criteria we should apply to the questions asked on *Drupal Answers*.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that if Drupal is (suspected to be) either part of the problem or part of the solution, the question can be considered Drupal specific. If we're not sure, ask for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

There is a gray area and for some questions it's hard to tell until it's solved whether or not it truly was a Drupal question. The question you reference is a good match, on the surface it didn't look like a problem connected to Drupal, but once solved it showed that part of the problem related to the use of Drupal API.

I think we have to be careful not to become over zealous about which questions and answers belong here.

Comment: The problem I see with that question is that the way to find a solution is not specific to Drupal, in the same way a question about CSS is not specific to Drupal. The purpose of this question is to get some valid criteria on which we agree. I took that question just as example, but what I am asking here is something more general.

Comment: Actually, the error was passing to a Drupal function the name of a file that doesn't exist. Firebug is famous to report a document type error, in such cases; it seems the issue is more with Firebug, which should report a different error, instead of reporting an error with the document type.